# site's footer disappear when not logged in. only show up when logged in as Administrator?

Tags: blocks

Need help or guidance on this.  I don't understand why website's footer disappear when not logged in as administrator.  I am using OpenPublic openomega and delta themes.  The footer is generated from the main menu links.  I just don't understand why it disappears when not logged in as administrator.  Is there an area for the main menu where I can configure how it display's the footer and set permission's for it?  thanks for any info on this.

Comment: Do you have any content or blocks in the footer region?

Comment: This is where I'm getting lost,  when I go into Structure->Blocks I see "No Blocks in this Region" under every block that is listed. However, when I log in as an administrator,  the footer gets generated.  I also checked the appearance section to see if there's anything I can configure with permissions but I don't see anything there. I inherited this site and the previous admin just told me that the footer is generated by the Primary menu.  Thanks for the reply Patrick.

Comment: Blocks aren't always placed through Structure > Blocks, they can also be placed through Context.
Check if site has Context module, and if so, check there.